# SQL sys.tables formatting

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I can get the databases and the tables like the following:

[image]

But what I want as a result is

[image]

How can I do that? I want to improve the formatting but I do not know how.

Answer (score 7):

Why does this need to be done in T-SQL? Presentation is not SQL Server's job. Since the client has to loop through those rows to display them anyway, it can keep track of the last table it saw and only print the name on the new row if it's different.

Yes, there are ways to produce this output using SQL Server alone, but I'm reluctant to show them to you because you're liable to use them instead of performing this presentation work where it belongs.

```
SELECT
```

> `[table] = CASE`
>    `WHEN LAG(t.name,1) OVER (ORDER BY t.name, c.name) = t.name THEN ''`
>    `ELSE s.name + N'.' + t.name`
>  `END,`

```
[column] = c.name
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c
ON t.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
ORDER BY t.name, c.name;
```

Comment: @Kin ha, sadly the spoiler doesn't support pre or br.

Comment: Thanks! I spent so much time trying to figure out the equivalent of Oracle's BREAK ON and your LAG line easily did it -_- thanks

Comment: @Sara I may not have made this clear, but *you really shouldn't be doing this presentation work in the database*.